# Using DialogFlow to login in my application

Tags: javascript, authentication, dialogflow-es, addeventlistener

Well i've searched here and in the documentation of dialogflow and coulnd't find any help in this subject.
I have an aplication and I want to use dialog flow to login in my website, there is a db where my login infos are stored.
So i'm only looking to say to the bot that I want to log in, it will ask my credentials and compare with the ones in my db.
Is there any docs about it? Where could i find something to help me in this?

Perhaps i din't explain well what i want or maybe did something wrong...
Reading through the doc i noticed that i can add js events to the chat...

```
    const dfMessenger = document.querySelector('df-messenger');
dfMessenger.addEventListener('event-type', function (event) {
  // Handle event
  ...
});
```

Something like this, i grabbed this code from here https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#js-events

Can i use this to create a function were i grab the users info and authenticate in my database to login in the application?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly advanced stuff and I would start with a more basic chatbot before attempting any of this.

I liked Lilis is a first hands in project into dialogflow ES but you could find your own. https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/build-dialogflow-chatbot-lilis-1-what-are-the-top-seven-minimum-viable-product-features-of-a-998d6bfb60e7

It goes through how to structure a chatbot before how to design it which can be a vital step, limiting the abilities before coding starts.

DialogFlow allows you to make a basic/advanced CA.

User asks a question, CA either replies automatically or fetches a reply.

Dialogflow has a language behind it if you're fetching a reply, Python, Node, Java, C...

All of those languages can connect to a database and check the database parameters on the background once a chatbot gets the propper input then the chatbot can reply based on wether there was a match and the code has done the appropiate changes to the URL, for example.

If you're using the default webhook it needs to be done in node.

Dialogflow can do just about anything that can be done reasonably quick on the background as it supports most of the top coding languages for the replies on the background

Comment: Well i played around for a bit with dialogflow. I think i've achieved something similar to what lilis offer. What i'm struggling with is thinking of a way to capture what I type in the chat and transform that in a an aswer to questions of login. Like i thought of some possibilities, using one accordion and input a form in it and try to capture it on my angular app, trying to capture data using events in ts. My app is running in angular it's frontend and the back is a springboot project.

Comment: Again any advanced stuff goes into the webhook. You can use google's provided webhook or your own, I recommend self hosting one in glitch or similar. In the webhook you can check those things you want using Node, Java..., and then make a login request to an endpoint in your angular API or similar before providing a reply. This is not doable with inbuilt dialogflow functions AFAIK

Comment: Yeah, your comment gave me a new light to this project. I've found some videos on youtube saying how to basically do it.

Here you manage to get a response with webhook:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUlI8R1u9TE&t=1s

and here you can manipulate the data:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz_dKRZP_cE

So i guess that doing this two things i can use the data that i want and add it to a function were I can login.